How can I create an action for my own GPT app that can be append additional text to users' questions
I have created my own custom GPT using the "My GPTs" platform on GPT4. Now I want to add a new action to this app, via My GPTs -> choose my custom GPT -> Configure -> Actions -> Create new actions
This action should be:

Trigerred by any question asked by the user
Append an additional content onto the question, and then pass the question to GPT.

The problems I met are:

I can't find anywhere to configure the triggers of the actions.
I tried to waite a piece of openAPI schema script to create the action, but don't know how to fill in the field of "servers" -> "url" field.

Could anyone who have GPT experience please kindly advise? Thanks a lot!

Have you written any code? If not, this is likely off topic for SO

You can't use Actions for this, Actions aren't for use cases like this, you may consider including the additional text in the instructions of the GPT and instructing it to consider it in the way you want
